# How did Stannis Baratheon survive the Battle of Blackwater?

Tags: game-of-thrones

This always confused me.  Stannis Baratheon (the one true king!) assaulted Blackwater Bay in *Game of Thrones* season 2 but lost.  In this scene here, you can see him being captured (go to the 4:25 mark):

How is it that he not only survives, but escapes?  In following episodes he's back at home licking his wounds...

Comment: It's obvious from the uniform/armor they wear. The red cloth were his men.

Comment: Then again, Tyrion was attacked by one of their own, and the constant back stabbing and changes of allegiance, maybe it wasn't so clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see in your own video how.

He's not being captured. Effectively, the battle is lost due to Tywin Lannister's arrival with the House Tyrell and **his own men** drag him away from the battle.

To quote from the relevant section in the book:

> Bronn smiled thinly. "From the winch towers, all we saw was banners in
> the mud and men throwing down their spears to run, but there's
> hundreds in the pot shops and brothels who'll tell you how they saw
> Lord Renly kill this one or that one. Most of Stannis's host had been
> Renly's to start, and they went right back over at the sight of him in
> that shiny green armor."
>
> After all his planning, after the sortie and the bridge of ships,
> after getting his face slashed in two, Tyrion had been eclipsed by a
> dead man. If indeed Renly is dead. Something else he would need to
> look into. "How did Stannis escape?"
>
> "***His Lyseni kept their galleys out in the bay, beyond your chain. When
> the battle turned bad, they put in along the bay shore and took off as
> many as they could.*** Men were killing each other to get aboard, toward
> the end."
>
> <sup>A Storm of Swords - Chapter 4 (Tyrion)</sup>

Comment: Hmm.. that makes sense then...  thx!

Answer (score -2):

He was actually not being captured, but pulled by his own men to back off from the fight! Salladhor Saan was ready with his ships to pick him up.

Check the details answer here
https://www.quora.com/How-did-Stannis-Baratheon-escape-from-the-battle-of-Blackwater-in-Season-2-of-Game-of-Thrones

Comment: Are you able to describe what you found on the site instead of leading users on the SE website via link?